# XamDataGrid - filtering parent child hierarchical data

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a XamDataGrid which displays a hierarchical data similar to a directory structure (folders can have folders and files inside).
I have a separate TextBox outside the grid where i enter the search string and in the TextChanged i apply RecordFilters to the FieldLayouts.

The requirement is if there is a file matching the search string, its parent folders (till root) should also be visible. But other files should not be visible.

If the directory and its child directories and child files doesn't match the search string, they should all be made invisible.

If the directory matches search string and its child directories and files doesn't match, only that base directory should be visible.

What I have done is to apply the recordfilter to both the parent and child fieldlayout, if a parent directory doesn't match the search, it will be hidden even if the child matches the field.

Whats the best approach to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with Linq combined with recursion.

Something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using rekie;

namespace System.Collections.Generic
{
  public static class FilterExtension
  {
    private static string _criteria;

    public static IList<Node> FilterBy(this IList<Node> source, string criteria)
    {
      _criteria = criteria;

      var copySource =
        (from n in source
         select n).ToList();

      foreach (var node in source)
      {
        if (node.Offspring != null)
        {
          FilterRecursion(node);
        }
      }

      return copySource;
    }

    private static void FilterRecursion(Node parent)
    {
      foreach (var node in parent.Offspring)
      {
        if (node.Offspring != null)
        {
          FilterRecursion(node);
        }

        node.Visible = node.Text.Contains(_criteria);
      }

      parent.Visible = parent.Text.Contains(_criteria) || parent.Offspring.Where(o => o.Visible).Count() > 0;
    }
  }
}

namespace rekie
{


  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var orig = Node.GetSome();
      var Results = orig.FilterBy("O.o");
    }
  }

  public class Node
  {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public IList<Node> Offspring { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    public static IList<Node> GetSome()
    {
      return
        new List<Node>()
        { 
          new Node()
          { 
            Text="Chidori", 
            Offspring=new List<Node>()
              { 
                new Node(){ Text="Rasengan "}
              }
          }, 
          new Node()
          { 
            Text="Kage Shuriken no Jutsu", 
            Offspring=new List<Node>()
            {
              new Node(){Text="Amagumo O.o"}
            }
          }, 
          new Node()
          { 
            Text="Kage Bunshin no Jutsu", 
            Offspring=new List<Node>()
          }, 
          new Node()
          { 
            Text="Oiroke no Jutsu", 
            Offspring=new List<Node>()
            {
              new Node(){ Text="O.o"}
            }
          }, 
          new Node()
          { 
            Text="Ranshinsho O.o", 
            Offspring=new List<Node>()
            {
              new Node(){ Text="Shikotsumyaku" },
              new Node(){ Text="Byakugan"}
            }
          }
        };
    }
  }
}
```